# Jumping back in an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have code looking like this:

```
var choice1 = prompt("a question").toLowerCase;

if (choice1 === option) {

      alert("Something")
}

else {

      alert("that's not possible")
      go back to the original prompt

}
```

So, how would I go about going back to the original prompt to ask the question again?

Comment: By using a loop construct. Either a for or while. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: You want to do a infinite loop? just encapsulate everything into a `do{}while()`  loop and set the while conditional statement to something like `i == true` and the code should run forever until the program is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
var flag = false; 

while (!flag) {
    var choice1 = prompt("a question").toLowerCase;

    if (choice1 === option) {    
          alert("Something");
          flag = true; // set flag to true to break out of the loop
    }    
    else {    
          alert("that's not possible")
          // go back to the original prompt    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the entire code block inside a function, and call it again if you don't get the answer you want.

```
function askQuestion() {
    var choice1 = prompt("a question").toLowerCase;
    if (choice1 === option) {
         alert("Something");
    } else {
         alert("that's not possible");
         //go back to the original prompt
         askQuestion();
    }
}
```